# Dockerised Hive does not find org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem even though I added the hadoop-aws jar

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, docker-compose, hive

I am trying to PoC a docker-compose composed of HDFS & Hue & Hive + connected to my AWS S3 Buckets.
As of right now I have it running and I can browse my S3 Buckets using Hue File browser.
When I try to create a hive external table on my parquet file, I get the following error :

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

I understand this is caused by a missing hadoop-aws jar.
As a quick win, I've uploaded the hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar to the container HDFS, and executed my create table query after

> add jar hdfs:/hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar;

I don't get any errors so it seems to find the jar properly (if I change the name, I get an error file not found). Yet the create external table still fails with the same error.

What am I doing wrong ? I though it could be related to an incompatible version but it seems to be matching my docker-compose versions.

Here is the docker-compose used :

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    volumes:
      - namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    ports:
      - "50070:50070"
    
  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    volumes:
      - datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070"
    ports:
      - "50075:50075"

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432 resourcemanager:8088"
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  huedb:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresl/data/
    ports:
      - "5432"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
        SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432 resourcemanager:8088 hive-metastore:9083"
  
  hue:
    image: gethue/hue:4.6.0
    environment:
        SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:50070 datanode:50075 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432 resourcemanager:8088 hive-metastore:9083 huedb:5000"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./hue-overrides.ini:/usr/share/hue/desktop/conf/hue-overrides.ini
    links:
      - huedb

volumes:
  namenode:
  datanode:
  pg_data:
```

Would love any help !!

Thanks,

Comment: I've ran into similar issues, and didn't find a solution, but want to point out that you don't need 2 Postgres servers. You can also use one Minio container instead of HDFS+Namenode